# On Information-less systems

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, universe, information

Is there any system in the universe that is information less, I.e., has or possesses no [physical information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_information).

For example if I have a system of particles and if I throw this system into a black hole(BH), I can access the information of the system as long as the system is outside the event horizon, but once it is inside the BH, I can never obtain or retrieve any information about it;  but this doesn't imply that the system of particles has become an information-less system.
Classically, a black hole is independent of its past history.How does the information of the quantum state of the infalling particles re-emerge in the outgoing radiation?

Hawking in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01147v1) paper says that:

> Polchinski recently used a shock wave approximation to calculate the shift on a gen- erator of the horizon caused by an ingoing wave packet. Even though the calculation may require some corrections, this shows in principle that the ingoing particles determine a supertranslation of the black hole horizon. This in turn, will determine varying delays in the emission of wave packets. The information about the ingoing particles is returned, but in a highly scrambled, chaotic and useless form. This resolves the information paradox. For all practical purposes, however, the information is lost.

Is there any other example of a system possessing no information?

Comment: I can think of 1 "system"  possessing no information, but this is not the place for politics. Seriously  I think you should include a definition of information in your post.

Comment: @Lol! Yeah,thanks! I have edited and provided a link which aims to define what I mean by information.

Comment: There is no such wikipedia article at the moment.

Answer (score -3):

Information is inherant for any system,  even a one particle system,  as it pertains to relationship not only to Self but to Any other members of the set. 
There are no non informational systems.

Comment: Can you expand this more, particularly the first sentence (e.g., references to back it up). If you don't, this may be deleted as it has been marked as [low-quality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606)

Comment: Perhaps your understanding of the response is of equal quality.....

Comment: Judge and jury..... Everyone has to be righter

Comment: You realize you're posting on a site in which the answers *are* judged? You are willing that to happen...

Comment: Again you miss the spirit of the content